# Changinge font size of a pdf file using Libre draw?

Tags: libreoffice, pdf

I can change the font size of pdf using Libre draw one line at a time. Since the file is big, I want to do that in one go. Any suggestion on how to do that?

Comment: Please add information on how you are actually changing it one line at a time

Answer (score 1):

*Readable text* from PDF is imported in LibreOffice Draw as **Text objects**, one for each line because that is also how text may be coded into the PDF. Bear in mind that **PDF was never designed to be editable**.

You can change the font size of multiple text objects in Draw by *selecting* them, then changing the font size via the Properties pane on the right, or via the Format - Characters dialog. Because Draw is a drawing program, you work with one page at a time.

Depending on the nature of the document, it could, or could not, be interesting to manipulate the text using *styles*. You then would select all text and clear direct formatting (Format - Clear direct formatting). Then, by editing the style, you would change the appearance of all text. Selected text, e.g. headings, could then be manually assigned a different style.

Another way, if you really need to totally re-typeset the document, would involve *export the text* with a commandline tool like `pdftotext` or `pdftohtml` and then importing the resulting text file into Libreoffice Writer. There, typesetting will be more convenient. The figures could then be transferred from the PDF document open in Draw.

In the end, it will all require **significant manual labor**. PDF is not designed for such operations, so you may **want to avoid reformatting a PDF** unless absolutely necessary for some reason.